# How to replace an CMFCPropertyGridCtrl with a new one inside CDockablePane

Tags: c++, mfc

i have created CMFCPropertyGridCtrl inside an CDockablePane and i want to replace this CMFCPropertyGridCtrl with a new one, then i override OnEraseBkgnd.
OnEraseBkgnd called only in the application start, and when i want to call it by Invalidate or InvalidateRect it didn't fire.
How can i call OnEraseBkgnd?
Thanks in advance.

```
void CCL2PropertiesPane::HostPropertyGridControl(CMFCPropertyGridCtrl* pPropertyGridControl)
{
  if(NULL == pPropertyGridControl)
    return;

  if(m_pPropertyGridControl)
    RemoveCurrentPropertyGridControl();

  m_pPropertyGridControl = pPropertyGridControl;
  SetWindowText(m_pPropertyGridControl->GetName());

  CRect clientRectangle;
  GetClientRect(&clientRectangle);
  m_pPropertyGridControl->Create(WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, clientRectangle, this, PROPERTIES_DOCKABLE_PANE_ID);
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void CCL2PropertiesPane::RemoveCurrentPropertyGridControl()
{

  m_pPropertyGridControl = NULL;
  SetWindowText(GetPaneName());

  CRect clientRectangle;
  GetClientRect(&clientRectangle);

  //here i want to call OnEraseBkgnd
  InvalidateRect(clientRectangle);
  //Invalidate();
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
BOOL CCL2PropertiesPane::OnEraseBkgnd(CDC* pDC)
{
  CRect clientRectangle;
  GetClientRect(&clientRectangle);

  CBrush whiteBrush(RGB(250, 250, 250));
  pDC->FillRect(clientRectangle, &whiteBrush);

  return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Something is wrong with your code, but we cannot help you, unless you provide a [mcve]. Make sure to read [ask] for general guidelines on asking questions.

Comment: Is this edit acceptable? @IInspectable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `ON_WM_ERASEBKGND` to `CCL2PropertiesPane`'s message map to properly erase the background. Or move the `FillRect` function in to `OnPaint`.

Regarding:

```
void CCL2PropertiesPane::RemoveCurrentPropertyGridControl()
{
    m_pPropertyGridControl = NULL;
    ...
}
```

Above code is appropriate for initialization, but it doesn't remove or destroy anything. The control is still there, it only makes the program forget how to find the control. To hide the control use:

```
m_pPropertyGridControl->ShowWindow(SW_HIDE);
```

To destroy the control use `DestroyWindow()`, but that's not recommended with above setup.

Comment: Thank you @Barmak Shemirani